# I am getting (Cannot assign "11": "Notification.user_to_notify" must be a "User" instance.) in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Below is my code. I have 2 models Post and Notification. Whenever any user likes any post i am adding that to notifications tables. and getting '**Cannot assign "11": "Notification.user_to_notify" must be a "User" instance.**' this error.

```
#Post model
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank=True)
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

#Notification model
class Notification(models.Model):
    user_to_notify = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'user_to_notify',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_who_fired_event = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name= 'user_who_fired_event' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seen_by_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


postExists = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)  
# posted_by is having relation with User
notification = Notification()
notification.user_to_notify = postExists.posted_by.id(ERROR)

#also tried
notification.user_to_notify = postExists.posted_by(Still getting ERROR)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `.id` from `postExists`, that should fix the issue

```
postExists = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)  
# posted_by is having relation with User
notification = Notification()
notification.user_to_notify = postExists.posted_by
```

Because `user_to_notify` expects a User instance, not an integer. But, if you want, you can still use integer, like this:

```
notification.user_to_notify_id = postExists.posted_by.id
```

Underneath ForeignKey, django creates a column with `<field_name>_id`, so when you used `notification.user_to_notify_id`, you can set an integer there. More information can be found in [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#database-representation).